# Repeating characters in string do not send

Tags: java, string, printing

Hi so I know there is most likely a way better way to write this that is more efficient but I am just playing around with Java and am making a program where if you type a work it is the same work but the letter opposite in the alphabet. The problem I am having is that repeating letters do not repeat in the execution of the program. Is there a way to fix it? Here is the program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
 
        char A = 'Z';
        char B = 'Y';
        char C = 'X';
        char D = 'W';
        char E = 'V';
        char F = 'U';
        char G = 'T';
        char H = 'S';
        char I = 'R';
        char J = 'Q';
        char K = 'P';
        char L = 'O';
        char M = 'N';
        char N = 'M';
        char O = 'L';
        char P = 'K';
        char Q = 'J';
        char R = 'I';
        char S = 'H';
        char T = 'G';
        char U = 'F';
        char V = 'E';
        char W = 'D';
        char X = 'C';
        char Y = 'B';
        char Z = 'A';
 
        System.out.println("Enter the message you would like to see in reverse: ");
        String message = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();


        if (new String(message).contains("A")) {
            System.out.print(A);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("B")) {
            System.out.print(B);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("C")) {
            System.out.print(C);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("D")) {
            System.out.print(D);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("E")) {
            System.out.print(E);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("F")) {
            System.out.print(F);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("G")) {
            System.out.print(G);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("H")) {
            System.out.print(H);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("I")) {
            System.out.print(I);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("J")) {
            System.out.print(J);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("K")) {
            System.out.print(K);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("L")) {
            System.out.print(L);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("M")) {
            System.out.print(M);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("N")) {
            System.out.print(N);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("O")) {
            System.out.print(O);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("P")) {
            System.out.print(P);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("Q")) {
            System.out.print(Q);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("R")) {
            System.out.print(R);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("S")) {
            System.out.print(S);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("T")) {
            System.out.print(T);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("U")) {
            System.out.print(U);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("V")) {
            System.out.print(V);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("W")) {
            System.out.print(W);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("X")) {
            System.out.print(X);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("Y")) {
            System.out.print(Y);
        }
        if (new String(message).contains("Z")) {
            System.out.print(Z);
        }

 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your approach does not work because you're just checking presence of the letter in message, but completely ignoring its position

probably something like that is simpler:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the message you would like to see in reverse: ");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String message = scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase();

    for (char letter: message.toCharArray()) {
        if (letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'Z') {
            letter = (char) ('Z' - (letter - 'A'));
        }
        System.out.print(letter);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```